# asp.net dynamic data NEW custom page ERROR NOT FOUND

Tags: asp.net

iv added a new folder inside my 'customPages' folder 'Check' i've then added a new webform page inside the 'check' folder called 'show'

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="show.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicData_CustomPages_Check_show" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    bla bla la
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

when I try to navigate it from another page it wont work ERROR: 28889/CRC/Check/show.aspx

```
The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /CRC/Check/show.aspx
```

any idea as to why?

---

EDIT:iv even set it as my start page my right clicking, but it still cant find the page?

Answer (score 0):

You said that you added a WebForm called List, so instead of show.aspx, you should try list.aspx.

Comment: sorry my mistake that was a typo it is actually called show. il correct it in the edit thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your `new folder` is in your `custompages` folder than `url` shoould be like this

> YourApplication/customPages/Check/show.aspx

I think you are missing `customPages` folder

Comment: played about with all that still cant get it

Comment: Also a working example is the 'Diary_Documents' folder which is inside the custom pages so http://localhost:28889/CRC/Diary_Documents/Details.aspx works fine but CRC/Check/show.aspx cant be found

Comment: CRC is your application name then where is custompages in the url?

Comment: iv tired CRC/DynamicData/CustomPages/Check/show.aspx but it doesnt work either?

Answer (score 0):

Open Global.asax

There should be something like this:

```
routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx") {
            Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert" }),
            Model = model
        });
```

Add 'Show' in the action list.